# URL with ".profile" returning 403 error

Tags: url, google-oauth, query-string

Any URL that has in the query string '.profile' returns a 403 error.

For example:

```
example.com?data=user.profile
```

I can't just remove the string, because I'm using Google OAuth and upon callback, it's part of scopes.

```
example.com/callback/?code=###&scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile#
```

I guess it is considered a .profile file, but how can I make it behave as expected?